# How to output the number of vertices, edges and faces given a polygon with Python?

Tags: python, vertices, edges

So far I have written the following code. I am super new to python

```
class polygon(object):
    def__init__(self, edge, face, vertex='')
        self.edge = edge
        self.face = face
        self.vertex = vertex
        self.tetrahedron = tetrahedron

a = polygon('6', '4', '4', tetrahedron)
print a.edge, a.face, a.vertex, a.tetrahedron
print a
```

Also How can find the mesh module in Python? I am using spyder and I cant find it in the library.  Please help if anyone can.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the active object for instance:

```
ob = bpy.context.object
```

And get its data (if it's a mesh object, the mesh datablock):

```
me = ob.data
```

Mesh element counts:

```
len(me.vertices)
len(me.edges)
len(me.polygons) # faces
```

Vertex count of a single face:

```
len(me.polygons[0].vertices)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, everytime I put bpy it says it is not recognized or no such module found. Please pardon my lack of knowledge. I started using python 2 days ago for the first time. How can fix that? I am using spyder IDE. But thank you a lot for your help

Comment: You need to run it inside of Blender, which comes with its own Python 3.x and the bpy module.

Comment: So can I use the same code to find vertices and faces in like tetrahedron?

Comment: what about find all vertices count in the scene?

Comment: @fourtwo It's pointless to sum up the vertices of all meshes in a scene IMO, because it's ill-defined. Should it include invisible objects, instantiated groups, etc.? And if you want to include modifiers then you either have to apply them (e.g. using a temporary mesh object) or rely on what Blender shows in the status bar (`bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)` but beware, this is mode dependent! Old script which ensures object mode: https://github.com/CoDEmanX/blend_stats/blob/master/blend_stats.py)

Comment: @CodeManX could you check my post here tell me what could i do with my verts count.. I understand what you say about mode dependent and the modifiers and such and that's a great pointer, didn't think about that, will definitely would like to use just the scene.statistics i think..   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167862/create-n-panel-button?noredirect=1#comment283331_167862