# How to create a button on the n-panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, vertices, panel

I would like to make a custom button on the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel.

I already went through blender's templates and amended the ui button script to 2.8 but I don't understand where and how I should implement my code into the template.

Also I would love to be able to remove doubles and display the current vertex count next to it before and after the operation:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

for ob in scene.objects[:]:
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.02)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

**Q:** How can I add a custom button with that functionality on the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel?

Comment: Related re remove doubles multiple mesh objects. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68133/15543

Comment: Still having issues with showing the vert count

Comment: @brockmann THANKS A LOT! works like a charm

Comment: @brockmann, i think so.. it does what i want it to do
what's wrong with it?

Comment: Added a "final version". I guess your version is even 2 or 3 times slower than my optimized version of your code. Just ask if there is something you do not understand. ...And please don't use this code in your question...

Comment: Editted your question according to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I suggest start here: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)*

To extend the *Properties Area* of the *3D View* you can either *register a custom panel* to add UI elements onto *or* you can append elements to [existing panels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3452/31447).

---

### 1. Panel

Blender comes with a few UI templates *(Text Editor > Templates > UI ...)* . I'd suggest start with *UI Panel Simple* `ui_panel_simple.py` and use it as base to work on. You just have to edit its default variables in order to display the `HelloWorldPanel` as part of the properties panel:

- Set [`bl_space_type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_space_type#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type) to `'VIEW_3D'` to make it part of the 3D View
- Set [`bl_context`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_context) to eg. `'mesh_edit'` or `'objectmode'` to either match *Edit* or *Object Mode*

```
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Sub-Panel in the Property Area of the 3D View"""
    bl_label = "My Tool"  
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"  
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Tools"
    bl_context = "mesh_edit" # "objectmode"
```

The `HelloWorldPanel` comes with a predefined `draw` method where you can edit the layout as well as adding UI elements to the panel. *More interestingly:* You can easily add existing operators like `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()` to the panel by calling the `operator()` method on the layout element like `row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")` without the namespace (`bpy.ops*`).

```
row = layout.row()
# bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

row = layout.row()
# bpy.ops.object.origin_set()
row.operator("object.origin_set").type="GEOMETRY_ORIGIN"
```

To pass multiple arguments read: [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2515/31447)

---

### 2. Operator

If you want a custom function assigned to a *button*, you'll have to create a new operator. Blender comes with `operator_simple.py` template which is easy to understand. In most cases it's enough adding your code to the `execute` method, which will be called when the button is pressed.

```
def execute(self, context):
    my_variable = "Hello World"
    print (my_variable) # Prints 'Hello World' to the Console
    self.report({'INFO'}, my_variable) # Reports 'Hello World' to the Info Area
    return {'FINISHED'} # Return the execution is finished
```

If you want to call another operator as part of the operation like `bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()` which only works on *meshes*, it's a good idea to limit the scope to *mesh objects* using the provided `poll` method, even if the operator is only accessible in *Edit Mode* because otherwise the operator is still callable using the *Search Menu* (<kbd>F3</kbd>):

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    obj = context.active_object
    return (obj is not None and obj.type == 'MESH')

def execute(self, context):
    # Your code here
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.02)
    # ...
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Also read: [What do operator methods do? (poll, invoke, execute, draw & modal)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19431/31447)

If you want to display the vertex count after `mesh.remove_doubles`, you can store the vertex count before calling the operator and then `report` the actual result:

```
def execute(self, context):
    obj = context.object
    verts_before = len(obj.data.vertices)
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.02)
    verts_after = len(obj.data.vertices)
    result = verts_before - verts_after
    self.report({'INFO'}, "Verts removed: {}".format(result))
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

---

### 3. Registration

Register your classes properly, add your operator(s), labels, and properties to the panel:

```
import bpy

class MY_OT_custom(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return (obj is not None and obj.type == 'MESH')

    def execute(self, context):
        # Your code here 
        # ...
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.02)   
        return {'FINISHED'}


class MY_PT_custom(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Sub-Panel in the Property Area of the 3D View"""
    bl_label = "My Tool"  
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"  
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Tools"
    bl_context = "mesh_edit"

    def draw(self, context):
        obj = context.object

        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: {}".format(obj.name))

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Vertex Count: {}".format(len(obj.data.vertices)))

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator(MY_OT_custom.bl_idname)



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_custom)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_custom)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_custom)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_custom)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

### Appendix

TLDR; If you want to 'remove doubles' (merge by distance) for multiple meshes in *Object Mode* for whatever reason, use the `bmesh.ops.remove_doubles()` operator as [suggested by @batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167862/create-n-panel-button#comment283331_167862), it's **3 times faster**.

#### [`bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles)

As of 2.8x we can enter *Edit Mode* for all selected objects simultaneously, which avoids looping over all the objects as well as switching to *Edit Mode* and *Object Mode* each iteration so **your code can be simplified** as follows:

```
def execute(self, context):
    # get all mesh objects in selection 
    meshes = set(o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
    # store the vert count on all objects
    verts_before = sum([len(o.data.vertices) for o in meshes])

    # switch to edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # select all vertices
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # remove the doubles
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.01)
    # switch to object mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    # store the vert count again
    verts_after = sum([len(o.data.vertices) for o in meshes])
    self.report({'INFO'}, "Verts removed: {}".format(verts_before-verts_after))

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Although this saves a lot of time, it still takes **0.0814 seconds** for 100 cubes with a vertex count of 8080.

#### [`bmesh.ops.remove_doubles()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.remove_doubles)

```
    def execute(self, context):
        # get all mesh objects in selection 
        meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
        # store the vert count on all objects
        verts_before = sum([len(o.vertices) for o in meshes])

        # Remove doubles using bmesh based on:
        # https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68133/31447
        bm = bmesh.new()
        for m in meshes:
            bm.from_mesh(m)
            bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=self.merge_dist)
            bm.to_mesh(m)
            m.update()
            bm.clear()
        bm.free()

        # store the vert count again
        verts_after = sum([len(o.vertices) for o in meshes])
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Verts removed: {}".format(verts_before-verts_after))
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Bmesh method takes **0.0290 seconds** for 100 cubes with a vertex count of 8080.

---

#### Final Panel & Operator

Panel in *Object Mode* and a proper implementation of the operator *(Undo, Merge Distance etc.)* in order to remove possible doubles for *all objects in selection*:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

class MY_OT_rem_doubles_bmesh(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Remove Doubles on Objects in Selection"""
    bl_idname = "object.remove_doubles_bmesh"
    bl_label = "Remove Doubles (bmesh)"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    merge_dist: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Merge Distance",
        description="Merge Distance",
        min=0.0,
        step=0.1,
        default=0.02
    )

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return (obj is not None and obj.type == 'MESH')

    def execute(self, context):
        meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
        verts_before = sum(len(o.vertices) for o in meshes)

        # Remove doubles based on:
        # https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68133/31447
        bm = bmesh.new()
        for m in meshes:
            bm.from_mesh(m)
            bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=self.merge_dist)
            bm.to_mesh(m)
            m.update()
            bm.clear()
        bm.free()

        verts_after = sum([len(o.vertices) for o in meshes])
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Verts removed: {}".format(verts_before-verts_after))

        return {'FINISHED'}



class MY_PT_custom(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Sub-Panel in the Property Area of the 3D View"""
    bl_label = "My Tools"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        sel_objs = context.selected_objects
        sel_vert_count = sum(len(o.data.vertices) for o in sel_objs if o.type == 'MESH')

        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator(MY_OT_rem_doubles_bmesh.bl_idname)
        layout.separator()

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="{} Objects in Selection".format(len(sel_objs)))

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Vertex Count: {}".format(sel_vert_count))



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_rem_doubles_bmesh)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_custom)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_rem_doubles_bmesh)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_custom)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I see what you did there... thanks a lot for the detailed appendix :) I have one question: 
merge_dist: bpy.props.FloatProperty..  how come it moved into the class and why you need the name, description, min, step ? @brockmann

Comment: The reason is simple: Adding a property to the operator makes it accessible in the UI  ([Operator Panel or F6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129016/31447)), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYr8C.png Adding `min`, `max`, `step` etc. to the [FloatProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FloatProperty.html?highlight=floatproperty) just avoids the user is doing any mistakes, it's an *intentional limit*. Imagine a script adding subsurf modifiers to each object and the user accidentally sets the subsurf value to 100 ...  @fourtwo

Comment: I understand, but there is no input from the user in this script @brockmann

Comment: That's just the way blender works and I added that for completeness because usually you want interaction. Also it's nice to have it there in case... if you don't like it for whatever reason just throw it away and replace `self.merge_dist` with a float value like `0.01`: `bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=0.01)`, easy but not that user friendly IMHO @fourtwo

Comment: no it's good to know, thanks again ;)

Comment: No need for list. `sum(len(m.vertices) for m in meshes)`

Comment: Cool, changed to generator expression as suggested @batFINGER