# Change default_frames_limit trough Text Editor script

Tags: python, movie-clip-editor

I want to change the default_frames_limit in the movie clip editor. I found a script in a addon that does exactlie that:

```
clip = bpy.context.edit_movieclip
clip.tracking.tracks.data.settings.default_frames_limit = 10
```

But it just works from within the movie clip editor, not from a text editor script.
How could I change this value from a different context?

Comment: I guess you'd like to run your script for a movie clip which is already loaded into the editor right? If so, I'd suggest to write a custom operator to call your "script" from F3 or to add a button to that editor, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167862/how-to-create-a-button-on-the-n-panel/167870#167870

Comment: Thanks for the link might work it into a fully-fledged addon, fo now the answer below was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Its the clip associated with the space.**

Similarly to a text in the text editor, an image in the image editor, what is known as the `context.clip` in the movie clip editor, is the clip assigned to the space.

To the python console:

Loop thru the screens to find a movie clip area and return its active space.

```
>>> def get_clip():
...     for s in D.screens:
...         for a in s.areas:
...             if a.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
...                 return a.spaces.active
...     return None
...     
>>> mc = get_clip()
>>> mc
bpy.data.screens['Default.002']...SpaceClipEditor
```

The active clip of that space

```
>>> clip = mc.clip
>>> clip
bpy.data.movieclips['Batman_(1966)_S01E01.mkv']

>>> clip.tracking.tracks.data.settings.default_frames_limit
0
```

Comment: As expected, good taste when it comes to movies.

Comment: Here's a one-liner replacement for the `get_clip` function: `mc = next((a for s in D.screens for a in s.areas if a.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR'), None)`. Not a fan of unreadable code like this, but sometimes you need a single statement (e.g. in drivers).